# What to call money set aside for incidental expenses?

Tags: single-word-requests, money

I have seen my father give some amount of money to my mother saying that it was for incidental expenses or asked her to spend on inessentials.

What is the right word for *the money allotted/set aside for incidental expenses*?

Comment: [allowance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allowance_(money))

Comment: Are you looking for "pin money"? A small sum of money for spending on inessentials. (historical) An allowance to a woman from her husband for clothing and other personal expenses. http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/pin-money

Comment: In business contexts this is (or used to be) called *petty cash*. In domestic contexts, I can't think of a name for the money, but the container it's in (and, by synecdoche, the reserve itself) is call *the kitty*.

Comment: Its container is canonically the **cookie jar**. (You might call such money *cookie-jar* money, but I don't think I've ever heard that.)

Comment: *Contingency fund* would be money set aside for emergencies or other unexpected expenses.  But the term implies that the money should not be used for non-essentials.

Comment: Broadly that would be petty cash… the point being that if the amount is large enough to care about, it should be accounted for in a specific account heading, not as "incidental." Even if your dictionary or search engine had trouble with that, don't you think it belongs under some heading dealing with book-keeping or accounts specifically; general English could happily accept 37 terms, from "pocket-money" on…

Answer (score 6):

**spending money** is an allowance for small personal expenses. It is extra money that you can spend on whatever you want, e.g. on ​activities you ​enjoy, ​entertainment, ​personal things, etc;

Example: *How much ​spending ​money are you taking on ​holiday?*

Answer (score 3):

Discretionary, as in discretionary spending, usually used to indicate non-essential

Comment: Could you offer some supporting evidence for your suggestion? It's always a good idea to include cited references, definitions or published examples, as appropriate, with your answers.

Answer (score 2):

'Money set aside for incidentals' in a domestic context is sometimes called *housekeeping*, but this often includes groceries, so may not suit your purpose.

Answer (score 2):

Consider, **pocket money**.

> : cash for day-to-day spending on incidental expenses - [**Princeton
>   University, Farlex
>   Inc**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/pocket+money)
>
> : (chiefly AmEng) A small sum of cash, carried on the person, for
>   small, daily expenses
>   [**Wiktionary**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pocket_money)

Answer (score 2):

A **Nest Egg** could be a candidate:

> a fund of money accumulated as a reserve
>   [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nest%20egg).
>   "Paid for the computer out of his nest egg"
>
> (idiomatic) A savings; a reserve of money. [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/nest_egg)  "Over time, they
>   accumulated a tidy nest egg and retired comfortably."

A nest egg might imply a longer period of accumulation than *allowance* or *emergency fund*. But a quite useful expression.

[Case Dough](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/case-dough) could be considered, too.

> A small amount of money set aside for emergencies; mad money (1940s+)

[The Dictionary of American Slang, Fourth Edition by Barbara Ann]

Answer (score 1):

## Petty Cash

In a business environment, the ubiquitous term for the pool of money, typically managed by a secretary or office manager, that one might spend on incidentals without having to fill an expense report, is **Petty Cash**.

I've also heard it used in non-business settings, but not as frequently referring to a pool of money, but more typically as an adjective describing the amount of money as being *petty* or trivial.

#### Example:

> Yeah, Kobe is amazing.  He bought that new whip with petty cash.

#### The OP's situation

That being said, in the example you provided, I believe **petty cash** would be a perfect fit.  Imagine your Father saying:

> Here Dear, put this with the petty cash.

or

> Here Dear, add this to the petty cash.

#### Reference

From [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/petty%20cash):

> **petty cash** noun
> Definition of petty cash
> : cash kept on hand for payment of minor items